# How to get polygon points in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I am drawing polygon by capturing mouse clicks on canvas and then passing these points to `fabric.Polygon`. So, in this manner I'm drawing multiple polygons.

What I need know is, I want to get the mouse co-ordinates (pixel points on canvas) for the polygon which is selected now?

I have tried with:

```
canvas.getActiveObject().get('points');
```

But this is giving some negative and some positive values.

So, can u please tell me a way to find out the polygon points?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Polygon points are relative to its center so you can get their "absolute" position like so:

```
var polygon = canvas.getActiveObject();

var polygonCenter = polygon.getCenterPoint();

var translatedPoints = polygon.get('points').map(function(p) {
  return { 
    x: polygonCenter.x + p.x, 
    y: polygonCenter.y + p.y
  };
});
```

Let's check how this looks:

```
translatedPoints.forEach(function(p) {
  canvas.getContext().strokeRect(p.x-5, p.y-5, 10, 10);
});
```

[image]

I think this will only work if polygon's angle is at 0 (otherwise need to "rotate" points coordinates as well).

Comment: Thank you so much...
It really helped me to proceed further with my project

Comment: @kangax - thanks for this answer it helped, is there a way to get the proper co-ordinates when the polygon is rotated?

Comment: this no longer works in the latest version of Fabric JS - is there an update?

Comment: If you create a new polygon it can happen, that the points are not relative to the center but absolute. (tested with v2.4.1)
Ironically exporting and reimporting changes that back to relative points.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that from version 2.0 they changed the coordinates of the polygon. Before 2.0 points relative to the center of the polygon; after 2.0 they are absolute to the canvas;

Check out my response to the similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710375/4681279