# Find Coordinates of the Active Object in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, coordinates, fabricjs

Using fabric js i draw a different shapes such as circle ,rectangle
.I tried

the rectangle is drawn by `fabric.rect() method`

```
 canvas.getActiveObject().get('points');
```

but it returns `undefined`

I have also gone through this post

[How to get polygon points in Fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854808/how-to-get-polygon-points-in-fabric-js)

but i cannot solve the issue

```
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var objectCenter = object.getCenterPoint();
    var translatedPoints = object.get('points');
    console.log(object);
    console.log(translatedPoints);
    translatedPoints.map(function(p) {
        var pt =  {
            x: objectCenter.x + p.x,
            y: objectCenter.y + p.y
        };
           console.log(pt);
```

Is there any way to find the coordinates of the rectangle or other active objects drawn by similar methods

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
alert(obj.left + "," + obj.top);
```

Comment: How can i find object height & width? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985469/get-height-and-width-of-fabric-js-object-after-modifying-wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data for all objects on your canvas, you can create a JSON object using the following code. Coordinates for all of your objects will be included as properties in the output (along with object height & width - per Chirag's question in the previous answer).

```
function serializeCanvas(c) {
    var canvasJson = JSON.stringify(c);
    console.log(canvasJson);
}
```