# Get height and width of Fabric.js object after modifying wrong

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Here is my code.

```
<canvas id="c" width="240" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
     canvas.backgroundColor = 'yellow';


     canvas.renderAll();

     fabric.Image.fromURL(<?php echo '"' . $url . '"'; ?>, function(myImg) {
      var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:150,height:150});
      canvas.add(img1); 
     });

     function objectMovedListener(ev) {
      let target = ev.target;
      console.log('left', target.left, 'top', target.top, 'width', target.width * target.scaleX, 'height', target.height * target.scaleY);
     }

    canvas.on('object:modified', objectMovedListener);
</script>
```

I don't understand what's going wrong. object position TOP & LEFT is showing correct but height & width is shoving wrong.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Use [getScaledWidth()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledWidth) and [getScaledHeight()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledHeight) to get transformed width and height of an object respectively.

Comment: Thanks for replay, i updated my code i got value correct, but i have a question getting value is in `PX` or `%` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check `target.scaleX` and `target.scaleY`. If are different than 1 you need to multiply the `target.width` and `target.height` with scale

Comment: Thanks for replay, i updated my code i got value correct, but i have a question getting value is in `PX` or `%` ?

Comment: The value is in pixels

Comment: How can i get value in % ?

Comment: `(target.getScaledWidth()/canvas.getWidth())*100` -for width                                      `(target.getScaledHeight()/canvas.getHeight())*100` -for height