# class doesn't exist in type 'ILineOptions' on fabricjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, fabricjs

I'm trying to implement this answer on typescript, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570603/8503317 on create Line, there is this options

```
var line = new fabric.Line(points, {
  strokeWidth: 2,
  fill: '#999999',
  stroke: '#999999',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  selectable: false,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  evented: false,
  class:'line', //THIS DOESN'T EXIST ON FABRIC.LINE OPTIONS
```

here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/gXQjdw)

But on that codepen, it is working and don't have any error. does anyone knows why?

EDIT

Here's my reproduce https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bkaelf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Since i haven't got any solution, i fix it by manually adding `class` property to `ILineOptions` to `@types/fabric`. it's working now, but it's not the best  solution. If you have found the best answer, please post a new answer

Answer (score 0):

I came across this example as well, and I implemented it successfully with Typescript. You actually don't need `class` property inside `ILineOptions`. If you are using the `polygonMode` variable, just check if it is true or not (instead of checking if `activeLine` is null or not and then check if `activeLine` has `class` property with value `line`). It's redundant because if `activeLine` exists within polygon mode, you can enter inside that condition.

Example:

```
if (polygonMode === true && activeLine){
   ...
}
```